# Generate PDF or HTML reports with SonarQube 3.7.4

Tags: html, pdf, report, sonarqube

With SonarQube 3.7.4 (we can't update it yet) we would like to be able to generate PDF or HTML reports.

It seems that this version (3.7.4) doesn't launch the post-jobs sonar (creating the PDF) during an analyse ?

=> Is there a simple way to be able to generate reports (no matter the format) with SonarQube 3.7.4 and keep our sonnar-runner configuration ?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Are you using [Sonar PDF Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the commercial [SonarSource Report](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/report/installation-and-usage/) plugin for this.